# Rails: need advice about slug, URL, and CJK characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, internationalization, slug

I'm actually building a multi-language application which will support at least English and Japanese.

The application must be able to have URIs such as `domain.com/username-slug`. While this works fine with Latin characters, it does not (or rather, it looks ugly) using Japanese characters : `domain.com/三浦パン屋`

I was thinking of using a random number when the username is Japanese, such as :

```
def generate_token
  self.slug = loop do
    random_token = SecureRandom.uuid.gsub("-", "").hex.to_s[0..8]
    break random_token unless self.class.exists?(slug: random_token)
  end
end
```

But I don't know if this is such a good idea. I am looking for advice from people who have already faced this issue/case. Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: I think you could use [babosa][1]. Which transliterates Japanese symbols into Latin sounds. Just an idea.


  [1]: https://github.com/norman/babosa

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the Japanese chars look like in the URL? Are they moji-bake'ed?

Comment: I don't think what you call `username-slug` is a "slug" in the StackOverflow sense of the word. The SO tag 'slug' means "a descriptive part of the URL that is there to make it more human descriptive". In a URL like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719796/rails-need-advice`, the part after 19719796 is descriptive but optional, and thus a "slug". What you have is the path-part of a URL. I extended the question title and tag list accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR summary:

- Use UTF-8 everywhere
- For URIs, percent-escape all characters except the few permitted in URLs
- Encourage your customers to use browsers which behave well with UTF-8 URLs

Here's the more detailed explanation. What you are after is a system of URLs for your website which have five properties:

1. When displayed in the location bar of your user's browser, the URLs are legible to the user and in the user's preferred language.
2. When the user types or pastes the legible text in their preferred language into the location bar of their browser, the browser forms a URL which your site's HTTP server can interpret correctly.
3. When displayed in a web page, the URLs are legible to the user and in the user's preferred language.
4. When supplied as a link target in an HTML link, forms a URL which the user's web browser can correctly send to your site, and which your site's HTTP server can interpret correctly
5. When your site's HTTP server receives these URLs, it passes the URL to your application in a way the application can interpret correctly.

[RFC 3986 **URI Generic Syntax**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2), section 2 *Characters* says,

> This specification does not mandate any particular character encoding
> for mapping between URI characters and the octets used to store or
> transmit those characters.... A percent-encoding mechanism is used to
> represent a data octet in a component when that octet's corresponding
> character is outside the allowed set or is being used as a
> delimiter...

The URIs in question are `http://` URIs, however, so the HTTP spec also governs. [RFC 2616 **HTTP/1.1**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2), Section 3.4 *Character Sets*, says that the encoding (there named 'character set', for consistency with the MIME spec) is specified using MIME's charset tags.

What that boils down to is that the URIs can be in a wide variety of encodings, but you are responsible for being sure your web site code and your HTTP server agree on what encoding you will use.  The HTTP protocol treats the URIs largely as opaque octet streams. In practice, UTF-8 is a good choice. It covers the entire Unicode character repertoire, it's an octet-based encoding, and it's widely supported. Percent-encoding is straightforward to add and remove, for instance by Ruby's [URI::Escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html) method.

Let's turn next to the browser. You should find out with what browsers your users are visiting your site. Test the URL handling of these browsers by pasting in URLs with Japanese language path elements, and seeing what URL your web server presents to your Ruby code.  My main browser, Firefox 16.0.2 on Mac OS X, interprets characters pasted into its location bar as UTF-8, and uses that encoding plus percent-escaping when passing the URL to an HTTP request. Similarly, when it encounters a URL for an HTTP page which has non-latin characters, it removes the percent encoding of the URL and treats the resulting octets as if they were UTF-8 encoded.  If the browsers your users favour behave the same way, then UTF-8 URLs will appear in Japanese to your users.

Do your customers insist on using browsers that don't behave well with percent-encoded URLs and UTF-8 encoded URL parts? Then you have a problem. You might be able to figure out some other encoding which the browsers do work well with, say Shift-JIS, and make your pages and web server respect that encoding instead. Or, you might try encouraging your users to switch to browser which support UTF-8 well.

Next, let's look at your site's web pages. Your code has control over the encoding of the web pages. Links in your pages will have link text, which of course can be in Japanese, and a link target, which must be in some encoding comprehensible to your web server. UTF-8 is a good choice for the web page's encoding.

So, you don't absolutely have to use UTF-8 everywhere. The important thing is that you pick one encoding that works well in all three parts of your ecosystem: the customers' web browsers, your HTTP server, and your web site code. Your customers control one part of this ecosystem. You control the other two.

Encode your URL-paths ("username-slugs") in this encoding, then percent-escape those URLs. Author and code your pages to use this encoding. The user experience should then satisfy the five requirements above. And I predict that UTF-8 is likely to be a good encoding choice.